# Javascript - Why sometimes it is "undefined" when using return?

Tags: javascript

The codes below works:

```
var myArray = [];
function myFunc(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if(myArray.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1){
        myArray.push(randomNumber);
        console.log(randomNumber); //; didn't use return
    } else {
        myFunc();
    }
}
for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
    myFunc();
}
```

While the following doesn't, both are almost the same except the following is using "return".

```
var myArray = [];
function myFunc(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if(myArray.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1){
        myArray.push(randomNumber);
        return randomNumber; // using return
    } else {
        myFunc();
    }
}
for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
    console.log(myFunc());
}
```

The results may not be the same as those are random numbers, please try to refresh it for several times.

I want to use return so that the value could save into the function.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `undefined` because you are not returning anything when `myArray.indexOf(randomNumber) != -1`. Try:

```
function myFunc(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if(myArray.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1){
        myArray.push(randomNumber);
        return randomNumber; // using return
    } else {
        return myFunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Yachay. In the else clause, I just want to run the function again if certain condition is matched. Do you mind to tell me why should I use "return myFunc()" instead of just running the function again? Thanks again

Comment: Because, otherwise, when you call "myFunc" again the  returned value is lost.

Comment: Thank you very much Yachay! Have a nice day.